# How to insert data to database with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to insert my data to database from form.

My URL to create the data is `web.com/siswa/create`

But when I click submit system show error **MethodNotAllowedHttpException**.

How I can fix it? Is there anything wrong with my code?

Here is my form:

```
<form action="{{ url('siswa') }}" method="POST">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="exampleInputEmail1">NISN</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nisn" id="nisn" placeholder="NISN"></div>
         <div class="form-group">
         <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nama Siswa</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nama_siswa" id="nama_siswa" placeholder="Nama Siswa"> </div>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm font-weight-bold">Submit</button></form>
```

Controller:

```
public function tambah()
    {
      return view('siswa.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
      {

        $siswa = new \App\Siswa;
        $siswa->nisn = $request->nisn;
        $siswa->nama_siswa = $request->nama_siswa;
        $siswa->tanggal_lahir = $request->tanggal_lahir;
        $siswa->jenis_kelamin = $request->jenis_kelamin;
        $siswa->save();
        return redirect('siswa');
      }
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/siswa/create', [
    'uses' => 'SiswaController@tambah',
    'as' => 'tambah_siswa'
]);

Route::get('/siswa', [
    'uses' => 'SiswaController@store',
    'as' => 'simpan_siswa'
]);
```

Comment: You only have `get` routes but your form is trying to `POST`

Comment: i change it but now system show me error `419
Sorry, your session has expired. Please refresh and try again.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your `store` function route from `get` to `post`

```
Route::post('/siswa', [
'uses' => 'SiswaController@store',
'as' => 'simpan_siswa'
]);
```

Use Csrf protection field in your form for the session timeout error

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

OR

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" id="csrf-token" value="{{ Session::token() }}" />
```

OR if you are using Form builder

```
{!! Form::token() !!}
```

Comment: i change it but now system show me error 419 Sorry, your session has expired. Please refresh and try again.

Comment: you need to refresh the form and try again as csrf protection will not allow to refresh the form itself from clicking `f5`

Comment: yup fix it with add '{{ csrf_field() }}' in the form.

Answer (score 3):

In Route please use `post` instead of `get`

```
Route::post('/siswa','SiswaController@store');
```

and also include `{{ csrf_field() }}` in form

Answer (score 0):

you are using `method="POST"` on your form but in on your route you are using `Route::get`

Use `Route::post` for your route

Answer (score 0):

In your form you've given POST method, but your router doesn't have any POST handler. So all you have to do is , when you are trying to store data from form to DB you have to post the data, and the router should handle it.

Try this

```
Route::post('/siswa', [
'uses' => 'SiswaController@store',
'as' => 'simpan_siswa'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using POST method in your form and using GET in route.

try this

```
Route::post( '/siswa', [
    'uses' => 'SiswaController@store',
    'as'   => 'simpan_siswa'
] );
```